# Use of "um" with "werden"

Tags: meaning, preposition

> Entweder du stirbst als Held, oder du lebst lang genug **um** der Böse zu werden

Could someone please explain why "um" is the preposition of choice in this specific context? Couldn't find anything relevant elsewhere.

Comment: "um" is no preposition here, but a conjunction. Looking that one up in a dictionary might help you.

Comment: There is a mandatory comma missing before *um*, which might have helped you recognize that *um* is a conjunction here (meaning *in order to*), not a preposition.

Comment: This is from "The Dark Knight" by the way. The full quote in English: "You either die a hero, or you live long enough to see yourself become the villain."

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, this isn't a preposition, but a conjunction: "um … zu (infinitive)" is how you say "to" in the sense of "in order to" in German. So the sentence means "or you live long enough (in order) to become the villain".

Do a web search for something like *um zu sentences* for more information; there is also a German-language Wikipedia article on [um-zu sentences](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um-zu-Satz).